# Android SharedPreferences persistent within session but not across sessions

Tags: android, persistence, sharedpreferences

I starting playing around with this yesterday, so I expect I'm doing something very stupid.

My app has two classes / activities: PuzzleSelection and SolvePuzzle.

My PuzzleSelection onCreate looks like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_puzzle_selection);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int increment_puzzles_solved = intent.getIntExtra(PuzzleSelection.INCR_COUNTER, 0);
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int puzzles_solved = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.puzzles_solved), 0);
    if (increment_puzzles_solved > 0) {
        puzzles_solved += increment_puzzles_solved;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putInt(getString(R.string.puzzles_solved), puzzles_solved);
        editor.commit();
    }
    TextView puzzle_counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.puzzle_counter);
    puzzle_counter.setText(getString(R.string.puzzles_solved) + " " + puzzles_solved);
}
```

My PuzzleSelection activity includes a TextView that typically says "Puzzles solved: n" where n should increment each time you go to a SolvePuzzle activity and successfully solve it (which sends you back to PuzzleSelection with an IntExtra PuzzleSelection.INCR_COUNTER in the intent).

I'm testing the app by connecting my phone to my computer via USB, and sending the app to my phone using eclipse.

My counter works as expected *within* a session: the counter starts at zero, and increments each time I solve a puzzle. So the data seems to be persisting...

But the counter resets to zero if I restart the app. What am I doing wrong?  I thought my data would persist across sessions...

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

to

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(<PreferenceName>, <Mode>);
```

Use this in both activitites to get instance of `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: I changed to SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("com.example.myapp.data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); and I still get the same behavior.

Comment: Try changing the preference name to "MyPrefs"